# Is there a way to move the secondary axis title in Plotly (R) such that it does not overlap the markers?

Tags: r, plotly

The secondary (right) axis title overlaps the secondary (right) axis markers. Is there a way to move the secondary axis title such that it does not overlap the axis markers?

See below where "long title" overlaps the number 4.

```
plotly::plot_ly(data = mtcars) %>% 
  plotly::add_trace(
    x=~mpg, 
    y=~wt, 
    type='scatter', 
    mode='markers', 
    yaxis = "y",
    showlegend=F
  ) %>% 
  plotly::add_trace(
    y=~drat, 
    type='scatter', 
    mode='markers', 
    yaxis = "y2",
    showlegend=F
  ) %>% 
  plotly::layout(
    yaxis = list(
      title="wt",
      showgrid=F
    ),
    yaxis2 = list(
      overlaying = "y",
      side = "right",
      title = "long title"
    )
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://plotly.com/r/reference/scatter/#scatter-yaxis says yaxis:

> Sets a reference between this trace's y coordinates and a 2D cartesian y axis. If "y" (the default value), the y coordinates refer to `layout.yaxis`. If "y2", the y coordinates refer to `layout.yaxis2`, and so on.

Looking at https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-title-standoff

> Sets the standoff distance (in px) between the axis labels and the title text The default value is a function of the axis tick labels, the title `font.size` and the axis `linewidth`. Note that the axis title position is always constrained within the margins, so the actual standoff distance is always less than the set or default value. By setting `standoff` and turning on `automargin`, plotly.js will push the margins to fit the axis title at given standoff distance.

So I set `automargin = TRUE` and that seemed to do it.

```
plotly::plot_ly(data = mtcars) %>% 
  plotly::add_trace(
    x=~mpg, 
    y=~wt, 
    type='scatter', 
    mode='markers', 
    yaxis = "y",
    showlegend=F
  ) %>% 
  plotly::add_trace(
    y=~drat, 
    type='scatter', 
    mode='markers', 
    yaxis = "y2",
    showlegend=F
  ) %>% 
  plotly::layout(
    yaxis = list(
      title="wt",
      showgrid=F
    ),
    yaxis2 = list(
      overlaying = "y",
      side = "right",
      automargin = TRUE,
      title = "long title"
    )
  )
```

[image]